# how to add azure web role using rest api

Tags: java, azure

I have accomplished deploying a java web/worker role using Azure SDK for Eclipse with the help of the following site : http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Developing-a-Hello-World-Java-Application-and-Deploying-it-in-Windows-Azure1.aspx

Are there options to deploy a java web/worker role using REST APIs of Azure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hate when I see people not fully understanding Windows Azure to down-vote a very meaningful questions! If you don't know the answer, don't think the question doesn't make sense! Because this questions makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

From this tutorial you've learned how to directly deploy your application (web role) to Windows Azure. The Windows Azure Tools plugin for Eclipse have one more option - create package. If you just create a package you can use it to later deploy it as Cloud Service (that is the web/worker role) via REST API or PowerShell cmdlets.

However the process of using REST API will be a two step process:

1. You upload your package to an Azure blob storage using the [BLOB REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135733.aspx).
2. Create a production deployment for your cloud service pointing the correct package URI in the blob. Do this by using the [Azure Management REST API - Create Deployment operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460813.aspx);

Note that the REST Management API for Azure [is using client certificate for authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782.aspx), which you first have to upload via the management portal.

Comment: Adding to @astaykov's response: To consume Service Management API using Java, you may find this blog post useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/25/consuming-windows-azure-service-management-api-in-java/.